# not able to get scope value inside a ng-repeat function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have written like

```
<li class="abc" ng-repeat="data in datas" togglel = !togglel ng-click="showdata()">
```

but in showdata function i am unable to get the scope variable togglel. I know the workaround i.e. passing variable into function like  below

```
<li class="abc" ng-repeat="data in datas" togglel = !togglel ng-click="showdata(togglel)">
```

Is there any ways the first statement will work?

Comment: What does the controller have for a vm back?

Comment: It doesn't work because `ng-repeat` creates a child scope for each iteration. These child scopes, each, hold their own `togglel` variable. Instead, define an object (say, `vm`) in the controller (i.e. in the outer scope) and toggle its property: `togglel="vm.togglel"` (and, unrelated to the question, `data` is already plural - there is no such thing as `datas` :))

Answer (score 0):

You need to define togglel in your controller:

```
angular.module('yourModule',[]).controller('yourcontroller',function($scope){
   $scope.togglel = false;
   $scope.showdata = function(){
       $scope.togglel = !$scope.togglel;
   };
});
```